# Breadcrumb Navigation Link Tree Issue

Tags: php

I am working on a small script and needed to have a link tree. When I run my code Below in the desired file I get the following result -

Home  » 01st Doctor  » 002 The Daleks 1-7  » index.php

I need to make index.php not show up in the results.

So could someone out there tell me what I did wrong and how to fix it? Because I'm at a loss right now.

Thanks

```
if($location = substr(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), 1))
$dirlist = explode('/', $location);
else
$dirlist = array();

// Strip out unwanted file names
$dirlist = array_diff($dirlist, array("index.php"));

$count = array_push($dirlist, basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));

// path to main gallery location
$main_gallery = '/gallery';

$address = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$main_gallery;

echo '<div id="page_nav"><br /><br /><h2>';
echo '<a href="'.$address.'">Home</a>';

for($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++)
    echo '
        &nbsp;&raquo;&nbsp;<a href="'.($address .= '/'.$dirlist[$i]).'">'.$dirlist[$i].'</a>';

echo '</h2>';
```

Comment: Hmm, you probably won't want to hear this but you might want to consider a different approach. You're equating directory names to human-readable breadcrumb labels (since both the `href` and text of your links is the dir name). Plus, there's more elegant ways of approaching this sort of thing overall.

Comment: Solved the problem - Replace // Strip out unwanted file names
$dirlist = array_diff($dirlist, array("index.php"));

$count = array_push($dirlist, basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])); with  $count = count($dirlist);